# Issues with AI for a tic tac toe game in C++

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

So I'm having a few issues with my tic tac toe game's AI. The AI is meant to be purely defensive, so it will always block you. It works usually works initially with my first case, so for example if I play the top left then the top middle, it will always take the top right. Other cases, like if I play two diagonals, may freeze the game, or allow me a second turn. These problems arose only after I implemented my faulty smart AI. Initially, the program was had a 'dumb AI' that chose random spots as you'll see at the bottom of the code. Moreover, what I think the problem is is that the some of the blocking conditions can conflict with each other and cause problems. How can I fix this? Relevant code is as follows:
*The coordinates are based of of the tic tac toe grid where the top left is (0,0) and the bottom right is (2,2)*

```
void Game::AIGetNextMoveRand()
{
    //top row
    if(GetSquareState(0,0) == O && GetSquareState(1,0) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 2;
            AIMoveY = 0; 
        }
            while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);

    }
    else if(GetSquareState(2,0) == O && GetSquareState(1,0) == O)
    {

        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 0;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
            while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    //middle row
    else if(GetSquareState(0,1) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
        AIMoveX = 2;
        AIMoveY = 1;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(2,1) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
        AIMoveX = 0;
        AIMoveY = 1;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);    
    }
    // bottom row
    else if(GetSquareState(0,2) == O && GetSquareState(1,2) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 2;
            AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(2,2) == O && GetSquareState(1,2) == O)
    {
        do
        {
        AIMoveX = 0;
        AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    // vert 0
    else if(GetSquareState(0,0) == O && GetSquareState(0,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
        AIMoveX = 0;
        AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(0,2) == O && GetSquareState(0,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 0;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    // vert 1
    else if(GetSquareState(1,0) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {

        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 2;
        }
            while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(1,2) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    //vert 2
    else if(GetSquareState(2,2) == O && GetSquareState(2,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX  = 2;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(2,0) == O && GetSquareState(2,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 2;
            AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    // diagonal 1
    else if(GetSquareState(0,0) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {

        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 2;
            AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(2,2) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {

        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 0;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    //diagonal 2
    else if(GetSquareState(0,2) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 0;
            AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    else if(GetSquareState(0,2) == O && GetSquareState(1,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 2;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    // mid 0
    else if(GetSquareState(0,0) == O && GetSquareState(2,0) == O)
    {

        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 0;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    //mid 1
    else if(GetSquareState(1,0) == O && GetSquareState(2,1) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 1;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    // mid 2
    else if(GetSquareState(0,2) == O && GetSquareState(2,2) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 2;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    //diag 1
    else if(GetSquareState(0,0) == O && GetSquareState(2,2) == O)
    {
        do
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 1;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }
    //diag 2
    else if(GetSquareState(2,0) == O && GetSquareState(0,2) == O)
    {

        do 
        {
            AIMoveX = 1;
            AIMoveY = 1;
        }
        while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
    }

    else 
    {
    do 
    {
        AIMoveX = rand() % 3;
        AIMoveY = rand() % 3;
    }while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);

    }
    }

void Game::DoAITurnRand()
{
    AIGetNextMoveRand();
    SetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY,activePlayer);
    EndTurn();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops? Shouldn't it just need to move once per turn?

Comment: Is a minimal complete example too much to ask?

Comment: The initial AI code, the random space assignment, came from a tutorial I used to write this program. I just modeled the blocking code after that. All I know is that without that while loop, the AI is able to play in filled spaces, or the program freezes.                @ Beta, a complete example of what?

Comment: Get out a piece of paper, draw a tic tac toe board, and go through each of your test blocks. Some of them make sense, some of them don't.  For example, when (1,0) is an O, and (1,1) is an O, the AI should pick (1,2) to block, but it doesn't.  Instead, it tries to pick (1,0), which is already an O.  Or am I missing something about what your variables signify and what your functions do?

Comment: Nope, you've got it right. I just carelessly made mistakes in the coordinates. I'll fix them and see what happens.

Comment: I've fixed what errors I saw, but things still don't work. Here's a complete scenario: starting with the AI, the first move is (2,0), then (1,0), then (2,1), then (2,2), then (0,0), then (1,1), then (1,2), then (0,1), then the game freezes. I think it's because the AI wanted to play at (2,1), but it couldn't because it had already played at that space.

Comment: A minimal complete example of code that exhibits the problem. We can't compile the "relevant" code you've posted because it's missing a lot of crucial parts. See [sscce] (http://sscce.org).

Comment: I'll have to give you the whole package, since just the main .cpp can't run by itself. Everything runs off of a framework so there are several pairs of files that I'd have to include. Do you really want me to post all the files? I could upload them somewhere if you like. I'll put the framework on my public dropbox folder and post the link unless you want it some other way.

Comment: I'll need your DropBox member name in order for me to share the folder with you.

Comment: It sounds as if your code is unnecessarily interdependent. Do we really need the whole package to pass a single board state to the AI and get the next move?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, yes. I mentioned that I worked on this program from a tutorial.The person who does the tutorials provided a framework for us to work in. In it we have the main game.cpp and game.h files. In addition to those are pairs of files for graphics, the keyboard, and two other things. So I guess, everything is interdependent, and I'd agree that at this point the interdependence could be seen as unnecessary. However, our use of the framework is just for us to get used to it once we start actual directX programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do while loops are garbage. Think about it if your rules have made a wrong choice (i.e. tried to play on a filled square), then making the **same** wrong choice again isn't going to help. In fact that's why you get the 'freezes'. You need to reorganize the logic of your code. I would suggest that if your AI selects an illegal square then you should fall back to your random picking code, then at least you would get a legal move.

Something like this

```
// no move selected yet
AIMoveX = -1;
AIMoveY = -1;

// AI rules
if(GetSquareState(0,0) == O && GetSquareState(1,0) == O)
{
    AIMoveX = 2;
    AIMoveY = 0; 
}
else if(GetSquareState(2,0) == O && GetSquareState(1,0) == O)
{
    AIMoveX = 0;
    AIMoveY = 0;
}
// lots more rules
...

// check for fallback to random move
if ((AIMoveX == -1 && AIMoveY == -1)             // if no rules applied
    || GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY) // or if the square is not empty
{
    // pick a random square
    do 
    {
        AIMoveX = rand() % 3;
        AIMoveY = rand() % 3;
    }
    while(GetSquareState(AIMoveX,AIMoveY) != EMPTY);
}
```

I've initially set AIMoveX and AIMoveY to -1 to indicate that no rule has been picked yet. If they are still -1 after going through all the rules then I know that no rules got picked and I have to make a random choice. If a rule did get picked but it picked a non-empty square then I also make a random choice. I test for both of those conditions at the end of my code.

You have to think carefully about exactly what the code you write really does. Just putting a do while loop in one place because it worked in another place is not right.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm embarrassed for extrapolating the do while loop, but the lesson is now learned.